# Netsuite Data Integration to Oracle Analytics Cloud?

Tags: oracle, cloud, netsuite

I want to use Oracle Analytics Cloud for creating reports on the Netsuite data, what are the possible ways to do so?

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer, but check out Jitterbit IPaaS.  I've had luck connecting every system I've ever needed to, using it.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to pay extra for it, but netsuite offers suiteanalytics connect, which should give you odbc access to most netsuite data.  You can then configure oracle analytics cloud to connect to netsuite via the odbc connection.  Here's a link on oracle analytics cloud support for netsuite:  https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/analytics-cloud/acsds/supported-data-sources.html.